# fnmatch for windows in C?

Tags: c, windows

Is there a version of fnmatch for Windows? 
I'm trying to have the same functionality (basically using *'s from the command line for the filename) **in C** without having to call FindFirst() etc.

Code is appreciated.

EDIT: I need to accept wild cards from the command line for filenames, for example *.txt and be able to open each .txt file.

As I said, I don't want to use if possible FindFirst, FindNext.
Thanks

Comment: @Jessica: Can you kindly elaborate your question, possibly with an example?

Comment: do you know what fnmatch does? if not check http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fnmatch.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PathMatchSpec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773727.aspx)[Ex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773728.aspx) would be roughly equivalent, though it takes arguments in the opposite order.