# comparing strings to certain pattern

Tags: c

### #1

How can I check if the file is of a certain type?

I was trying to do it like this:

```
if(strcmp(filename, "*.txt") == 0){
    // do something
{
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work.

---

### #2

I know that I can not use the ***** in strcmp.
So how can I compare my string to a specific pattern?

For example:

```
if filename is ***.***.txt
do something
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Matching.html

Comment: I can't include the fnmatch.h file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for the last occurrence of `.` with [`strrchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr). If found, test against the *exact* string `.txt`:

```
ptr = strrchr (filename, '.');
if (ptr && strcmp(ptr, ".txt") == 0) {
    // do something
```

This won't even fail if the filename part of the full path does not contain an extension but the entire path does (then `strcmp` does not return `0`), or there is no full stop at all in the entire path (then `strrchr` returns `NULL`).

I prefer this method over manually counting the length of the extension, because it will work without adjusting with any length for the file extension.

Note that `strcmp` is strictly case sensitive. If your local library has either `stricmp` or `strcasecmp`, that may be a somewhat safer choice. (`stricmp` is Microsoft-only, `strcasecmp` is the more standard [Posix equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5918697/2564301).)

Answer (score 2):

You could try this.

```
int len = strlen(filename);
if (len < 4) {
   printf("Filename too short\n");
   exit(1);
}
const char *extension = &filename[len-4];
if strcmp(extension, ".txt") == 0
```

Comment: I'd prefer to see const char* extension, and don't forget to check that filename is of sufficient length for len - 4 to be valid.

Comment: Methinks len < 4 should result in the same behaviour as a non-zero strcmp.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `sscanf()`. Something like this:

```
int length = 0;
sscanf( string, "%*[^ \n\r\t.].txt%n", &length );
if ( length >= 4 )
{
   do_something();
}
```

The list of white space characters is probably not complete but will probably work for you.

Comment: Would upvote if you'd showcase how to check this for success / match. Both `[]` and `%n` are not exactly everyday features of `*scanf()`, and potentially confusing for beginners. (`length >= 4`?)

Comment: Actually I think you could skip %n and only check the return value of sscanf(), if it's not zero it'll match.

Comment: Return code is "the number of *input items* successfully matched *and assigned*". `%*[` suppresses assignment, `%n` is not an input item. Checked it, returns always zero, so `length >= 4` is the correct check. (Actually, since `".txt"` alone does **not** match -- `%[` matches 1..n, not 0..n -- any match gives `length >= 5`.)

Comment: Ah, bummer. I guess then you need to actually read something.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function exactly for what you're asking for with no tricks.
it's called `fnmatch`.

an example for usage:

```
int check_if_text( char *file_name ) 
{
    char *file_pattern = "*.txt";

    if ( fnmatch( file_pattern, file_name, 0 ) == 0 ) {
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

to use this function you will need to `#include <fnmatch.h>`

Comment: How can I do that on windows? When I try including fnmatch.h I get an error.

Comment: take a look at this SO question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364302/fnmatch-for-windows-in-c